# .Net Core application crashes on IIS when server restarts

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, iis

I have created a .NET core 5.0 project, that has multiple hosted services on it, and hosted on IIS. I have enabled application initialization in Windows features and added in web.config, also enabled preload for the application on IIS. Here are the contents of my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\Debug\net5.0\FaxApi.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        </environmentVariables>
        <handlerSettings>
          <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value=".\logs\aspnetcore-debug.log" />
          <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="FILE,TRACE" />
        </handlerSettings>
      </aspNetCore>
      <applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.htm" skipManagedModules="true">
        <add initializationPage="/swagger/index.html" />
      </applicationInitialization>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The following are the contents of my packages config:

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="5.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="RabbitMQ.Client" Version="6.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.11.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" Version="5.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="5.0.0" />
```

I have published it on my local machine and the application works perfectly fine on IIS restart and system restart. My system info is:

> OS : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763

> IIS : 10.0.17763.1

Now when I host this application on my live environment, it crashes whenever the server restarts but works fine when IIS restarts or the pool is recycled. The following crashing is seen when I try to access my API from browser when the server restarts:
[image: Error screen]

Live Server Info is:

> OS : Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Version 6.3.9600 Build 9600

> IIS : 8.5.9600.16384

Some people also included their stdout and stderr logs, so here are mine:

```
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Initializing logs for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.6\aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Process Id: 3364.. File Version: 15.0.21113.6. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: dc5e11abdb05b322f4b74b3afbcfb352fe984b2e.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Waiting for initialization
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting in-process worker thread
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Resolving hostfxr parameters for application: '.\FaxApi.exe' arguments: '' path: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Known dotnet.exe location: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Process path '.\FaxApi.exe' is not dotnet, treating application as standalone or portable with bootstrapper
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Checking application.dll at 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\.\FaxApi.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Checking hostfxr.dll at 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\.\hostfxr.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] hostfxr.dll found app local at 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\.\hostfxr.dll', treating application as portable with launcher
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Resolving absolute path to hostfxr.dll from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] hostfxr.dll located at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.6\hostfxr.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Parsed hostfxr options: dotnet location: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe' hostfxr path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.6\hostfxr.dll' arguments:
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Argument[0] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Argument[1] = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\.\FaxApi.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_IIS_HTTPAUTH=windows;anonymous;
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Loading hostfxr from location C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.6\hostfxr.dll
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Initial Dll directory: '', current directory: 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting dll directory to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting current directory to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Managed application exited with code 0
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting shutdown sequence 1
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Clr thread wait ended: clrThreadExited: 1
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Event Log: 'Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/FaxApi' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\' has exited from Program.Main with exit code = '0'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.' 
End Event Log Message.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Canceling standard stream pipe reader
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Stopping in-process worker thread
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Stopping CLR
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Event Log: 'Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/FaxApi' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely' 
End Event Log Message.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] InvalidOperationException 'CLR worker thread exited prematurely' caught at D:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\Servers\IIS\AspNetCoreModuleV2\InProcessRequestHandler\inprocessapplication.cpp:432 
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Failed HRESULT returned: 0x8007023e at D:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\Servers\IIS\AspNetCoreModuleV2\InProcessRequestHandler\dllmain.cpp:131 
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting app_offline monitoring in application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting file watcher thread
```

I could not find any solution to this issue even after investigating previously asked similar questions. I even tried to find out any outdated package but to no avail. Can anyone guide me on how this can be resolved?

Comment: Are you using c#? Why does it give .cpp file names?

Comment: @AliK that's because the native IIS module for hosting ASP.NET Core applications is written in C++

Comment: Yes I though so, but never seen an error directly refer to cpp just dlls.  Its strange though that you don't get the error on initial app start just on restart.  Would suggest maybe reinstalling the module.

Comment: @AliK
I have reinstalled the module but nothing changes.

Comment: The only thing I notice is that your are starting from debug folder while setting environment to production.

Comment: The path after publishing my application changes as follows.

`<aspNetCore processPath=".\FaxApi.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" hostingModel="inprocess" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />
        </environmentVariables>
        <handlerSettings>
          <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value=".\logs\aspnetcore-debug.log" />
          <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="FILE,TRACE" />
        </handlerSettings>
      </aspNetCore>`

But there is no difference.